# How to select custom posts thats are tagged with multiple taxonomies using wpdb

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wpdb

I want to select post id's of a custom post types (packages) that are tagged with multiple taxonomies (package_filters ['lights','sound','online']). The best I can do is this but its ugly.

```
    $sql = "SELECT id
            FROM $wpdb->posts
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
           WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'packages'
           AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'package_filters'
           AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'lights'

           AND id IN (
               SELECT id as post_id FROM wpmega_posts
                   LEFT JOIN wpmega_term_relationships ON (wpmega_posts.ID = wpmega_term_relationships.object_id)
                   LEFT JOIN wpmega_term_taxonomy ON (wpmega_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wpmega_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                   LEFT JOIN wpmega_terms ON (wpmega_term_taxonomy.term_id = wpmega_terms.term_id)
               WHERE wpmega_posts.post_type = 'packages'
               AND wpmega_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'package_filters'
               AND wpmega_terms.slug = 'sound' )";
```

Comment: Why not use `WP_Query` and `tax_query`?

Comment: because I'm using with ACF and I need to integrate with other SQL

Comment: I don't understand why that means you need to use SQL. What you want can be done easily with `WP_Query`

Comment: Thanks Tom I wish I had seen https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/